# ContextualVersionConflict while using snowflake-sqlalchemy

Tags: pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write a pandas DataFrame to snowflake using df.to_sql() but getting an error:

ContextualVersionConflict: (idna 2.10 (/mnt/shared//conda), Requirement.parse('idna<2.10'), {'snowflake-connector-python'})

my code

```
    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    try:
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        data = {
            'grant_type': 'password',
            'scope': 'SESSION:ROLE-ANY',
            'username': sf_schema,
            'password': password,
            'client_id': snf_url
        }
        response = requests.post(oauth_url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False, proxies=proxyDict)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    oauth_token = str(json.loads(response.text)['access_token']).strip()

    engine = create_engine(URL(
        account=account,
        role=role,
        user=sf_schema.lower() + "@<domain>.COM",
        warehouse=warehouse.upper(),
        database=database.upper(),
        schema=sf_schema.upper(),
        authenticator="oauth",
        token=oauth_token))

    connection = engine.connect()

    try:
        df.to_sql(sf_table_name, con=engine, index=False, chunksize=15000, if_exists='replace', method='multi')
        connection.close()
        engine.dispose()

    except snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error {0} ({1}): {2} ({3})'.format(e.errno, e.sqlstate, e.msg, e.sfqid))
        connection.close()
        engine.dispose()
```

I am able to read data from snowflake to pandas using snowflake.connector. So, connection is not an issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that snowflake-connector-python requires a lower version of the [idna](https://pypi.org/project/idna/) package. You can reinstall the correct version of idna with:

```
pip install 'idna==2.9' --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this solves your issue or not, but I would recommend leveraging the `write_pandas()` function instead of the `to_sql()` function, or the `to_sql()` function with the `pd_writer` method.

Both will leverage a PUT and COPY INTO to get the data into Snowflake, and avoid INSERT statements. These should be much faster (and possibly avoid the error you are getting).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#writing-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-snowflake-database